# How to get first page of pdf file as pdf programmatically?

Tags: android, pdf, pdfrenderer

I'm trying to get the first page of the PDF file as PDF. [PDFRenderer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfRenderer) helps to get the first page as Bitmap. My requirement is to get as PDF. I don't want to get Bitmap then write as PDF. Any best approach?

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried so far ?

Comment: Find some PDF parsing library, I guess. There is nothing built into Android for this.